# Python 3.7 в одной папке, но site-packages абсолютно в другой

Tags: python, python-3.x, idle

Установил python 3.7 в папку *Program Files/Python37*
После установил numpy, который оказался в * \AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\ *
В системной переменной Path определен путь именно к *Program Files/Python37*
Понятия не имею, почему именно туда установилось, **хотелось бы**, чтобы все библиотеки были именно в **Program Files/Python37/site-packages/**

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у вас установлены 2 версии Python. Проверьте, установили вы numpy для одной версии Python которая как-раз таки в \AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages.

Comment: Я вот тоже так думал, но в той папке(\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\) не было ничего кроме папки "site-packages".

Я даже удалял ту папку со всеми модулями, удалял полностью свой Python, потом устанавливал его обратно(в AppData/... всё ещё пусто), но после установки какого-либо модуля, он появлялся в \AppData\...\site- packages/

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае, установщик(я так думаю, может и не установщик) просто не имеет прав что-то устанавливать(хотя другие же программы устанавливаются...) в Program Files. Мне помогло просто использовать Командную Строку от имени администратора и модули устанавливались туда, куда я хочу